# Relationship between three matrices

Tags: matrices, transformation, symmetry

I think this might be an odd question, and a little vague.  But here goes.

This is related to coordinate transformations.  Three matrices are given: $G_1 , G_2$, and $\Lambda$.  $G_1$ and $G_2$ are symmetric.  (They are metrics, actually.)  $\Lambda$ is the matrix in question.  The three matrices satisfy

$\Lambda^{-1} = G_1^{-1} \Lambda^T G_2$

Is there anything we can say about the properties of $\Lambda$, such as it is symmetric, or it is either symteric or anti-symmetric, or ...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite this as $$G_1 = \Lambda^T G_2 \Lambda\,,$$
this is just the change-of-basis formula for a symmetric bilinear form. That is, $\Lambda$ is the matrix that interpolates from the expression for the metric in one coordinate system to the expression in another coordinate system. As it stands, $\Lambda$ could be any invertible matrix.